# Erro ao formatar o Json

Tags: json, aplicação-web, asp.net-web-api

Preciso gerar e expor um Json via web api e a dúvida é o seguinte: 
1o. - Tem como não expor o atributo `"services":null`, conforme o JSon gerado por mim descrito abaixo ? 
2o. - Como faço para gerar no inicio do Json: `"services": [` conforme o Json Solicitado ?

**Modelos:**

```
public class ProductType
{
    public ProductType()
    {
        services = new Services();
    }
    public string productType { get; set; }
    public Services services { get; set; }
}

public class Services
{
    public string subtype { get; set; }
    public string services { get; set; }

}
```

**Como deve ser o JSON:**

```
{
    "services": [
        {
            "productType": "Produto A",            
                "services": [
                    {
                        "subtype": "Sub Produto A1"
                    }               
                ]
        },
        {
            "productType": "Produto B",
                "services": [
                    {
                        "subtype": "Sub Produto A2"
                    }
                ]
        },
        {
            "productType": "Produto C",
                "services": [
                    {
                        "subtype": "Sub Produto A3"
                    }
                ]
        }        
    ]
}
```

**Como estou gerando o JSON:**

```
[
    {
        "productType":"Produto A",
        "services":
                {
                    "subtype":"Sub Produto A",
                    "services":null
                }
    },
    {
        "productType":"Produto B",
        "services":
                {
                    "subtype":"Sub Produto B",
                    "services":null
                }
    },
    {
        "productType":"Produto C",
        "services":
                {
                    "subtype":"Sub Produto C",
                    "services":null
                }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Opa, vamos lá.

você consegue sim ocultar, procure na API que você está utilizando qual o método ou anotação que você ignora os nulos.

exemplo, no jackson json você consegue fazer isso no mapper

mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);

quando a aparecer o rotulo de services, você pode criar um objeto Staff de JSON que contem um objeto do tipo services. Com isso, ele passará a ser criado.